# set visibility trough property not working actionscript 3.0

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, if-statement, flash, visibility

This is my first post.

```
if (condition) {
    trace("called");
    p[1].visible = false;
    j[1].visible = false;
}
```

With the code above "called" was printed in console but the both objects (buttons) still visible. Then when I try to put the set visibility (`p[1].visible = false;` and `j[1].visible = false;`) out from condition, it's work well.

I wonder what the problem here and how can I do set visibility with some condition?

**[EDIT]**

This is my actual source code. The code snippet above just to simple my question.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.ui.Mouse;
import flash.events.Event;

stop();

var isInit:Boolean;
var val:Array;
var p:Array;

if (!isInit)
{
    isInit = initial();
}

function initial():Boolean
{
    trace("init");
    val = new Array();
    val[1] = 0;
    val[2] = 0;
    val[3] = 0;
    val[4] = 0;
    val[5] = 0;
    val[6] = 0;
    pinit();
    jinit();
    ainit();
    binit();
    cinit();
    dinit();
    einit();
    return true;
}

function pinit():void
{
    p = new Array();
    p[1] = p1;
    p[2] = p2;
    p[3] = p3;
}

// event listener works
p[1].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function (event:MouseEvent):void {
    p[1].visible = false;
});
p[2].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function (event:MouseEvent):void {
    p[2].visible = false;
});

if (isInit)
{
    trace("set visibility"); // this is printed as well
    var i:int;
    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        setVisibility(i, val[i]);
    }
}

function setVisibility(num:int, val:int):void
{
    if (val==0)
    {
        p[num].visible = true;
        j[num].visible = true;
    }
    else if (val==1)
    {
        trace("one");
        p[num].visible = false;
        j[num].visible = false;
    }
    else if (val==2)
    {
        trace("two");
        p[num].visible = false;
        j[num].visible = false;
        a[num].visible = false;
    }
    else if (val==3)
    {
        trace("three");
        p[num].visible = false;
        j[num].visible = false;
        a[num].visible = false;
        b[num].visible = false;
    }
    else if (val==4)
    {
        trace("four");
        p[num].visible = false;
        j[num].visible = false;
        a[num].visible = false;
        b[num].visible = false;
        c[num].visible = false;
    }
    else if (val==5)
    {
        trace("five");
        p[num].visible = false;
        j[num].visible = false;
        a[num].visible = false;
        b[num].visible = false;
        c[num].visible = false;
        d[num].visible = false;
    }
}
```

The `ainit, binit, cinit, etc` functions are in another layer (on same frame) because the objects are there. The "one", "two", "three", "four", or "five" is printed but the visibility not set correctly.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  For anyone to answer your question, you'll need to edit it and include the code or explain how `p` and `j` get populated.   As it is right now, this question cannot be answered without it being a wild guess.

Comment: @Naqries Looks like everything should work, there has to be another reason, we can't see with a help of this information. Provide more code.

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis Thanks for your respond. `p` and `j` are array that referring to SimpleButton object. I was added more code above.

Comment: @AlexUsachov Thanks for your respond. I was added more code above.

Comment: That's much better, thank you.   Looking over your code, I still don't see where `j` is defined?    Are `p1`,`p2`,`p3` instances on your timeline?  Do those objects exist on other frames besides the frame that has this code?    Are you getting any error messages (make sure you're doing debug movie, and just play movie so you get error messages)

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis `j` is another simple button object in the same frame

Comment: You are treating `j` like it's an array. if `j` is a button, then you would do `j.visible = false`

Answer (score 0):

Just to make your code simpler and easier to read.

With your val array you can populate it like this

```
val = new Array (0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
```

Yes this has seven numbers as an array starts at 0. You don't have to reference it but I would populate it just to make it look nicer.

I also changed the if else bit at the end to this:

```
switch (val){
case 0:
        p[num].visible = true;
        j[num].visible = true;
        break;
case 1:
        trace("one");
        p[num].visible = false;
        j[num].visible = false;
        break;
case 2:
        trace("two");
        p[num].visible = false;
        j[num].visible = false;
        a[num].visible = false;
        break;
case 3:
        trace("three");
        p[num].visible = false;
        j[num].visible = false;
        a[num].visible = false;
        b[num].visible = false;
        break;
case 4:
        trace("four");
        p[num].visible = false;
        j[num].visible = false;
        a[num].visible = false;
        b[num].visible = false;
        c[num].visible = false;
        break;
case 5:
        trace("five");
        p[num].visible = false;
        j[num].visible = false;
        a[num].visible = false;
        b[num].visible = false;
        c[num].visible = false;
        d[num].visible = false;
        break;
}
```

As to your actual problem I don't think you can change a button from an array as it would become a copy of the button not the button itself (Hope that makes sense). I would still have the arrays but instead of the button visibility I'd use Booleans. So that at the end you could put:

```
btnButton.visible = p1;
```

Hope that's all Okay and of some use.